# Assuming EIP140, is remaining gas refunded when a called contract throws?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, evm, out-of-gas, revert-opcode

Under EIP140 (REVERT) and assuming Solidity ≥0.4.10. If I call from my contract to a function on an external contract, and this external function does an invalid jump, does my contract still call REVERT? If so, do I:

- pay only for total consumed gas
- pay for locally consumed gas, plus all gas Solidity sends to the external contract

I'm asking because I have a new contract that will call token contracts, some of which are compiled with older Solidity. But the way Solidity bubbles exceptions makes me believe that I would still benefit from REVERT and the lower gas cost. Is this correct?